# Adding emoij to input with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hey i've been trying to add emoji to input in selenium using python using js, but i can't post the comment, it's like placeholder which  isn't recognized by input bar

```
send = browser.find_element_by_class_name("x3qfX")
send.send_keys(wybor)
find_hastag = browser.find_element_by_class_name('yCE8d').click()
wejscie_zdjecia1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("X7cDz")

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
    var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
    elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      """
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea').click()
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
text = u'\u2764'
browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
#
```

`
btw i know the code itself might be disgusting, but everything beside that emoji input is working

Comment: Have you tried with just normal text (not an emoji) to check if the script is working?

Comment: I had the same problem then I noticed I could send emojis through python with no problem. I mean, I didn't use the code but the icon instead and works good! Maybe is not the best answer but... have you tried?

Comment: Alfa i actually didnt, i will try it

Comment: Alberto you used send_keys function? Because if so, its still not working in my case

Comment: no matter if it's text or emoji, still the same issue

Comment: @Kubson6969 I have an Instagram bot capable to comment user's pics and 1.- I use a list of emojis `emoji_list = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]` and 2.- send_keys to send emojis `comment_txtbox.send_keys(emoji_list[1])` and works good. I'm using python 3.7.4 and Firefox 81

Comment: I think the problem is with chrome driver itself, will try it with Firefox driver